# In Lingashtakam, does "Sanchit Paap" refer to "Sanchita Karma" or are these two separate concepts?

Tags: shiva, mantras, sanskrit, shloka, shiva-lingam

There is a verse in the Lingashtakam,

> कुङ्कुमचन्दनलेपितलिङ्गं पङ्कजहारसुशोभितलिङ्गम् ।
>
> सञ्चितपापविनाशनलिङ्गं तत् प्रणमामि सदाशिवलिङ्गम् ॥५॥

> kuṅkuma chandana lēpita liṅgaṃ , paṅkaja hāra suśōbhita liṅgam ।
> **sañchita pāpa** vināśana liṅgaṃ , tatpraṇamāmi sadāśiva liṅgam

What does "Sanchita Paap" refer to? Is it the same as Sanchita Karma?

Comment: Sanchita Papa = accumulated Papa (bad deeds). Whereas Sanchita Karma = accumulated deeds (both good and bad).

Answer (score 1):

*Sanchita papa* is similar to *sanchita karma*, but not exactly the same. You can figure this out by looking at the words' literal meanings. The word *sanchita* means 'accumulated,' or 'heaped.' ([source](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=sanchita&dir=au)) The word *papa* means 'sins,' 'crimes,' or 'bad deeds.' ([source](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=papa&dir=au)) The word *karma*, as you probably know, refers to *all* of one's deeds, not just the bad ones or the good ones.

So, sanchita papa means ‘accumulated sins’ while sanchita karma refers to ‘accumulated actions.’

In the context of the line, too, this makes more sense. *vinashaka* means ‘destroyer/destroys.’ ([source](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=vinashaka&dir=au)) So the line in question [*sanchita papa vinashaka lingam*] means:

> O linga, who wipes out all of one’s sins.

It would be weird if it said that Lord Shiva wipes out *all* karma. No, he wipes out only the bad deeds, or the accumulated sins.